# Шабаш и шабашка.

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

В разговорном языке не редко встречается слово "шабашка", означающее: неофициальная работа, подработка. И существует слово "шабаш" - слёт ведьм, колдунов и другой нечистой силы. Мне интересна история этих слов, а так же ваше мнение о том, есть ли между ними связь?

Answer (score 3):

Связь очевидна. *Шабаш*, по-видимому, происходит от еврейского *шаббат* - *суббота*, нерабочий день. Восклицание "шабаш!" означает "кончай работу!"
Ведьмы на шабаш слетались, насколько мне известно, в ночь с пятницы на субботу.

А *шабашка* - как правило, одноразовый заказ, выполняемый в свободное от основной работы время.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же, эти два слова являются этимологически однокоренными - от еврейского слова ШАБАТ, которое пишется с одной буквой "Б" и означает «покой, отдых, праздник субботы».

В русском языке слово «суббота» означает только день недели между пятницей и воскресеньем. Двойная буква «б» появилась в русском тексте из греческого правописания. В украинском тексте слово «субота» пишется с одной «б».

По закону Ветхого завета в день покоя-шабата запрещено делать повседневную работу и даже зажигать огонь для любой цели.

Кто-то придумал, что в то время, когда все благочестивые люди соблюдают установление о праздновании субботы из закона Божьего, наступает самое подходящее время для нечестивых существ устраивать свои разгульные празднества. Эти разгулы назвали шабашем ведьм.

Так как во время шабата устанавливается время покоя, отстранение от любой работы, то в русском языке словом "шабашка" называют все работы, производимые в это время в нарушение закона о соблюдении покоя.
Согласно словарю В. Даля, "Шабашки - дрова, щепа, обрубки, уносимые плотниками с работы домой". Скорее всего, это связано с библейской историей о собирателе дров в день шабата.

Comment: Есть в этом ответе неточность. Слово "шаббат" в русском языке пишется с удвоенной "б" (см. Википедию и Викисловарь). В иврите в этом слове пишется буква "бэт" с точкой внутри; эта точка называется дагеш и обозначает усиление звука, которое в русском передается с помощью удвоения согласных.